# There's a way to make one javascript framework use a jQuery versione and another one using another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frameworks

I'm using single-page-nav to have an 'animated' menu and Photoswipe for a photo gallery. The problem is I'm not able to have both work together. Now, if I have:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simple-inheritance.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code-photoswipe-jQuery-1.0.15.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $("#gallery a").photoSwipe();   
    });     
</script>
```

I've Photoswipe working, but not singlePageNav.. While doing:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simple-inheritance.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code-photoswipe-jQuery-1.0.15.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $("#gallery a").photoSwipe();   
    });     
</script>
```

I've singlePageNav working, but not  Photoswipe. Tried with jQuery 1.11.1, but none of them working.. I've see that: 
[Can I use multiple versions of jQuery on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page)
So I try:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_6_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){           
        jQuery_1_6_1("#gallery a").photoSwipe();    
    });     
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/simple-inheritance.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/code-photoswipe-jQuery-1.0.15.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js"></script>
```

but still no luck, none of them working.. Something else that I colud try, before looking for an alternative to Photoswipe?

Comment: First off, it's just not a good idea to try to use multiple version of jQuery in the same page.  You should research what the support jQuery versions are for each jQuery plug-in you're using and try to find some common ground between the two so you can use just one jQuery version.  That is the most desirable solution.  I would not recommend guess and test.  I would recommend research to find out what combinations are supported.

Comment: I tried, but going on Photoswipe site I didn't find that information. Instead I found "The call (if using jQuery)", that suggest that it can be used also without jQuery, like 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 Code.photoSwipe('a', '#Gallery');
}, false); but I could not make it work in that way. I was looking for an alternative, when I see the StackOverflow link for multiple version, and even if I don't like too the idea, I would give it a shot..

Comment: There is a separate non-jQuery version of PhotoSwipe (a separate version of PhotoSwipe).  I would suggest you use that one to solve your issue.  It also looks like the jQuery version of PhotoSwipe is built for jQuery mobile.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice it, tommorow I'm going to try!

Comment: Also, you can prevent jQuery from claiming the `$` global, and then call it using `jQuery("#gallery a").photoSwipe();` instead of `$("#gallery a").photoSwipe(); `.

Comment: Working with non-jQuery version! Tried with jQuery instead of $ (already tried with custom jQuery_1_6_1 $.noConflict variable) but not working, probably I'm doing something wrong.. non-jQuery version is ok to me, and I agree with better using one jQuery version.